# How to copy text message into PC

Tags: windows, windows-vista, software-rec, sms

I have approx 4 months of text message conversation from my mobile (samsung ) that I need to copy onto my pc (windows vista) .is there any free tool available for this or is there any other way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think you can do that with [Samsung PC Studio](http://www.samsungmobile.co.uk/supports/softwaremanuals/pcStudio31.do).

I have a Nokia and I do that with similar software (Nokia PC Suite).